# c# materialdesign PackIcon in ListBox

Tags: c#, xaml, icons, material-design

I want add array into ListBox and I want each ListBoxItem has its own text and Icon (PackIcon). I form the array and binding it into ListBox.

C#

```
       MenuItems = new[]
    {
        new MenuItem
        {
            Id = 0,
            Caption = "Item 1",
            Icon = "Pencil",
            Poeition = 1
        },
        new MenuItem
        {
            Id = 1,
            Caption = "Item 2",
            Icon = "Ticket",
            Poeition = 2
        },
```

XAML

```
            <ListBox
                x:Name="lbMenuPanel"
                Foreground="White"
                ItemsSource="{Binding MenuItems}"
                PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp="lbMenuPanel_PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp"
                ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">

                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Height="60" Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <md:PackIcon VerticalAlignment="Center" Kind="{Binding Icon}" />
                            <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource MenuTextBlock}" Text="{Binding Caption}" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

Text appears, but icon doesn't. How can I display dynamically  the icon (PackIcon Materialdesign). When I bind icon name lick a string it doesn't work.

I tried to do like this

```
new MenuItem
                {
                    Id = 1,
                    Caption = "Мои роли",
                    Icon = PackIconKind.Pencil,
                    Poeition = 2
                },
```

But doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple fix which I have tested. Instead of storing the actual PackIcons in your MenuItem rather store the string version.

```
MenuItem
{
    Id = 1,
    Caption = "Мои роли",
    Icon = PackIconKind.Pencil.ToString(),
    Poeition = 2
}
```

The 'Icon' variable is a string in my example.

Your xaml code above should work.

I have tried this and it works.

It might also be worth a try to set the size of the PackIcon, although this shouldn't be the problem.